# Como puedo hacer para que funcione mi lector de códigos QR y que el resultado se refleje en una textbox o listbox en una aplicación de escritorio?

Tags: c#, qrcode, aforge

soy nueva en esto, he estado intentando hacer un lector de codigos QR , con librerias como Aforge , barcode ,ZXing , etc. Por el momento mi adelanto ha sido el de encender la camara y programar una funcion para que este al tener la imagen capturada la extraiga del video y de el resultado en el listbox , e incluso he intentado experimentar con palabras en el codigo para verificar su funcionamiento, no obstante en todo he fallado, les adjunto un fragmento del codigo dentro de un timer.

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ESTAR SEGUROS QUE HAY UNA IMAGEN DESDE LA WEBCAM
            if (videoSourcePlayer1.GetCurrentVideoFrame() != null)
            {
                //OBTENER IMAGEN DE LA WEBCAM
                Bitmap img = new Bitmap(videoSourcePlayer1.GetCurrentVideoFrame());
                //UTILIZAR LA LIBRERIA Y LEER EL CÓDIGO
                string[] resultados = BarcodeReader.read(img, BarcodeReader.QRCODE);
                //QUITAR LA IMAGEN DE MEMORIA
                img.Dispose();
                //OBTENER LAS LECTURAS CUANDO SE LEA ALGO
                if (resultados != null && resultados.Count() > 0)
                {
                    //AGREGAR EL TEXTO OBTENIDO A LA LISTA
                    if (resultados[0].IndexOf("70707") != -1)
                    {
                        //QUITAR EL CODIGO DE VERIFICACION
                        resultados[0] = resultados[0].Replace("70707", "");
                        listBoxResult.Items.Add(resultados[0]);


                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error exactamante? Es un error o mensaje? porque no sabremos como ayudarte mejor